# Restricting NFC tag to only an application (Android)

Tags: android, nfc

I am fairly new in Android programming and am planning to work on a coupon system using NFC. I have read about reading and writing NFC tags through Android programming and have learnt about the intent filters.

My question is, is it possible to only program a tag so that it will only run my application, not any others. With that said, is it possible to make it not readable by any other applications? I'm quite blur about the types of tags and hope someone could clarify on this matter.

Comment: Will the app require network?

Comment: No it doesn't need a network. Just the NFC scan will do offline.

Answer (score 2):

You can mark the tag with a specific mime type, or even tag type, and write the intent filter in such a way that your application will get those tags. But other apps can just copy your intent filter and get notified of the tags too.

You can try encrypting the data on the tag so only your app can read that, but even that is far from flawless. Someone can easily decode the key from your APK. You can [encrypt your APK](http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2012/07/using-app-encryption-in-jelly-bean.html) too, but seems to be only supported on Jelly Bean and above.

It all depends on how much time and effort you're willing to put into hiding the contents of your tags, in comparison to how much time and effort your target audience will be willing to invest to crack it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! About the intent filters, if I want to read text data only from the tag, I use this manifest file?

AddActivityText(main, <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>)

I don't really understand the mimeType part. By implying "text/plain", does it mean that I want my app to run when the tag contains text data in NDEF format or something else? THanks for the clarification!

Comment: You should read [How NFC tags are mapped to MIME types and URIs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#ndef). Using this code will give you tags that are marked `TNF_WELL_KNOWN+RTD_TEXT` or `TNF_MIME_MEDIA+text/plain`. That doesn't seem like what you're looking for. Other apps may be registered for that. You should use your own private mime type. You can also use [AAR](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#aar), but it's ICS and above and might not be ideal if you want to support non-Android phones in the future.

Answer (score 0):

When you put an NDEF message on the tag (see [Ndef](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/Ndef.html)), you can add an [Android Application Record](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#aar) at the end of the [NdefMessage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefMessage.html). This will ensure that only your app will be started. If the app is not installed on the device, the user will be redirected to the Play Store app to install it (if it is available there).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use

1. An [Android Application record](http://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/source/browse/ndeftools/src/org/ndeftools/externaltype/AndroidApplicationRecord.java) (+[Mime record](http://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/source/browse/ndeftools/src/org/ndeftools/MimeRecord.java) if you want to support older phones)
2. An [Unknown record](http://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/source/browse/ndeftools/src/org/ndeftools/UnknownRecord.java) which only you understand, encrypted using private-public keys.

You might also be interested to see there is such a thing as a [Signature record](http://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/source/browse/ndeftools/src/org/ndeftools/wellknown/SignatureRecord.java).